# How Do I Convert Evernote Date/Time Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, evernote

The Evernote API and local SQLite database use a unusual format/type for date/time.
I have C# functions that do the conversion, but I need the same functions in JavaScript.

**I need two conversion functions:**
1.  Convert Evernote Date/Time TO JavaScript Date/Time.
2.  Convert JavaScript Date/Time TO Evernote Date/Time

Can anyone help?  I know nothing about C#.
I have searched here and the Evernote forums, but could not find a solution.

**This is NOT an exact duplicate of the indicated question:**
"*I am storing time in a MySQL database as a Unix timestamp and that gets sent to some JavaScript code. How would I get just the time out of it?*"

**for these reasons:**
1. I'm asking for conversion in both directions, whereas the other question is asking for only one way.
2. I'm dealing with SQLite whereas the other question is dealing with MySQL

```
public DateTime ConvertEvernoteDateToDateTime(long evDate)
        {
            // convert from seconds to ticks
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan((evDate * 10000));
            // create a date with the standard web base of 01/01/1970
            // add the timespan difference
            DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Add(ts);
            // adjust for the current timezone
            ts = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(date);
            date = date.Add(ts);

            return date;
        }

        public long ConvertDateTimeToEvernoteDate(DateTime date)
        {
            // adjust for the current timezone
            date = date.ToUniversalTime();
            // get the ticks as a base for the standard web base date
            long baseOffset = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
            // get the difference between the base and our date
            long evDate = date.Ticks - baseOffset;
            // convert from ticks to seconds
            evDate = evDate / 10000;

            return evDate;
        }
```

Comment: That sounds like standard UNIX time.

Answer (score 0):

That's regular UNIX time (seconds since 1970-01-01, UTC).

Javascript dates store milliseconds since that same origin, so you can simply multiply by 1,000, then pass that number to `new Date()`.

Comment: If you can provide a formula or function for conversion both ways, then I'll select your answer.